# Opencv for Java mobile phones midp2.0 mid1.0

Tags: java, opencv, lg, midp-2.0

I have recently completed my project in OpenCV 2.0 c++
This project is aimed for Visually Impaired persons. Basically Image is take through cam and then it is processed to guide the blind/ visually impaired person.

Now I want to test this project on a mobile device in different real scenarios. I have two mobile phones(sony erricsson w810i and LG KS360) which support JAVA apps. And I also read that OpenCV wrapper functions for java are available with the name JAVACV.

Can someone guide me if it is possible to write an app for testing my implementation? is JAVACV compatible with these old JAVA phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **not** possible. First of all because JavaCV is just a **wrapper**, that means that openCV must be installed on the system so that JavaCV can provide an interface through which you can access the methods in openCV.

Since you can not run opencv on these older phones, you will not be able to use JavaCV

Moreover, JavaCV requires Java SE 1.6, and the phones only support what is included in the  MIDP specification.

Mobile apps based on MIDP can not use the whole set of functions/classes found in Java 1.6(eg. you cannot use generics like `List<?>`, `Map<?>` etc.)